# The value for the Parameters sent as action to the Reducer for the useReducer Hook is showing as undefined in the console

Tags: reactjs

```
import styles from "./Row1.module.css";
import { useEffect, useReducer } from "react";
import PercentageBar from "./PercentageBar";

//Depending on the type of action we need to change the value of the state variables

const Row1 = (props) => {
  const Parameters = props.Parameters;

  const Reducer = (
    state = { Temp: 0, Hum: 0, AQI: 0, Pres: 0, Alt: 0 },
    action,
  ) => {
    console.log(action.Parameters);
    return { ...state, Temp: Parameters[0] };
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(Parameters);
  }, [props.Parameters]);

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(Reducer, {
    Temp: 0,
    Hum: 0,
    AQI: 0,
    Pres: 0,
    Alt: 0,
  });

  return (
    <div className={styles.row1}>
      <PercentageBar Percentage={state.Temp} />
      <PercentageBar Percentage={state.Pres} />
      <PercentageBar Percentage={state.Hum} />
      <PercentageBar Percentage={state.Alt} />
      <PercentageBar Percentage={state.AQI} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Row1;
```

In the following Component from my React Project I am using the useReducer Hook (Be it unnecessary in this project as I am trying to learn this Hook) and I am sending a Parameters array as the action in the dispatch function.
The issue seems to be that when I console.log the value of action.Parameters it's showing up as undefined in the console.
I am new to development & would love to learn my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to how your reducer is set-up, your reducer is expecting an `action` from the `dispatcher`. In your useEffect, you have dispatched `Parameters` as your action prop. So in-fact, `Parameters` is acting like the `action` value in this case. If you are expecting action to be an object instead, try implementing like this:

Reducer:

```
const Reducer = (
  state = {...initialValues},
  action,
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_VALUE':
      return { ...state, Temp: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Dispatch action:

```
dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_VALUE', payload: Parameters });
```

P.S. This could be a good example to understand why you should use typescript in your project as it can automatically detect the type issues and warn you about it. Hence, significantly reducing your debugging time.

Comment: The Parameters is fine, as when I console.log(props.Parameters) it's giving the expected output.

Comment: I guess I missed that you are trying to console log action.Parameters. Can you please try after changing it to just `console.log(action)`. Let me know if it works. I'll update my answer as well if it works.

Comment: So this is what I found out through your suggestion of console logging actions, when I console.log(actions) I am in fact getting the Parameters Array, so it is in fact getting dispatched, after seeing this I tried using the actions as the Parameters array in the Reducer function and it's now working just fine, so my doubt now is that if I am sending only one value through the actions (i.e. in this case the Parameters Array), can I not access it as actions.Parameters in the Reducer function?

Comment: Updated the solution @ShreshthSharma. Let me know if it resolves your query

Comment: Yes this did in fact solve the problem & I'll try to use TypeScript from here on out, thanks a lot!